# Dynamically change a value within a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of hostnames which i am using to populate an SCP command to transfer a file from the remote server to my local server. The problem is, some of the hosts do not connect via hostname, and i must use the IP. However this issue with this is that the file i want to transfer has the hostname in the filename, therefore i am using the list of hostnames to capture this, which becomes a problem when we go via the IP rather than the hostname

see code

```
hostnames = [
    'HOST1',
    'HOST2',
    '1.1.1.1', # HOST3
    '2.2.2.2', # HOST4

]

for host in hostnames:
    child = pexpect.spawn('scp user@{}:/var/log/{}.backup_file0.{}.gz /home/backups/'.format(host, host))
```

As you can see, host1 and host 2 will connect and successfully locate the correct file as we have used the hostname, for example:

host1.backup_file0.gz

host2.backup_file0.gz

However host 3 and host 4 will fail due to the hostname in the list being an IP, however the file on these hosts is using the hostname as opposed to an IP

As a note i am not connecting to these devices via ssh so i cannot use the socket to pull the hostname

Is there any way to dynamically map these hostnames / ips and use them as needed?

Comment: Hi, the IPS do not fail, what fails is locating the file on the host which is named with the hostname

Comment: What about using the `arp` table as a lookup for IP -> hostname? Or surely the host to IP mapping is in your `hosts` file. Or if you're unfortunate enough to be on Win, `ping -a` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see why you couldn't just match the ip with the hostname. Maybe use a dictionary:

```
hosts = {
  'HOST1': 'HOST1',
  'HOST2': 'HOST2',
  'HOST3': '1.1.1.1', # HOST3
  'HOST4': '2.2.2.2', # HOST4
}

for host, ip in hosts.items():
    child = pexpect.spawn(f"scp user@{ip}:/var/log/{host}.backup_file0.{date}.gz /home/backups/")
```

**Edit**, if I understand correctly you added that you do not have the hostname of hosts for which you connect via IP.

Maybe just try globbing then, as each host surely only backs itself up?

```
for host in hostnames:
    child = pexpect.spawn(f"scp user@{host}:/var/log/*.backup_file0.{date}.gz /home/backups/")
```